# Preloading both sides of an Ecto.Association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How can I preload both sides of a `has_many` and `belongs_to` association with Ecto?

For example, in a situation that where an article `has_many` comments and comments `belong_to` one article:

```
defmodule MyApp.Article do
  schema "articles" do
    has_many :comments, MyApp.Comments

    timestamps
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Comment do
  schema "comments" do
    belongs_to :article, MyApp.Article

    timestamps
  end
end
```

How can I create a query for an Article that preloads its `comments` association and the `post` association on each Comment without performing 3 separate queries? The third one to find each of the Posts again seems unneccessary.

```
# Does 2 queries to return the Article with `comments` preloaded but not
# the `post` on each Comment
Repo.get!(Article, 123) |> Repo.preload(:comments)

# Does 3 queries to return the Article with `comments` preloaded and
# preloads `post` for each Comment
Repo.get!(Article, 123) |> Repo.preload([:comments, comments: :post])
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly, but why can't you just leave it as it is? Making 3 queries is not much slower than making one, perhaps even faster than joining tables with left join or something like that.

Comment: My issue with making the 3rd query is that I have already done a query to fetch those records.

- Query #1 finds the Article with `id` 123
- Query #2 finds the Comments with `post_id` 123
- Query #3 finds the Article with `id` 123 again to set `post` on each Comment

Comment: Can you show the schema for Post? It only shows Article and Comment in the question.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "Post" I meant "Article"

Comment: I am not sure how to go about this, when you render articles you could just pass there an article and its comments, like this: `render MyApp.ArticleView, "article.html", article: @article, comments: @article.comments` and thus you don't need to preload articles for comments at all, you can just use the one you passed

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually about 2 things.

1. If you have one-to-many relationship, there's no need to "preload both sides", because all of records in the dependent table refer to the one record which they belong to. What sense would it make to introduce such circularity?
2. You want to eliminate number of queries in your examples. Right now you have there at least 2 queries, because first you fire a request to the database by issuing `Repo.get!`, then you make a second one with `Repo.preload`.

There are 2 forms of `preload` in Ecto - you can see them whey you type "preload" into a search box in Ecto documentation. The result is:

Ecto.Query
preload/3

Ecto.Repo
preload/2

First one is to be used inside queries.

You used the second, and here's what documentation says about it:
"This is similar to Ecto.Query.preload/3 except it allows you to preload models after they have been fetched from the database."

If you look at the examples for this function, you see that clearly you need already-fetched model (or models) to "fill" it with further values.

Looks like this is not what you want - you need to get rid of the first `Repo.get`. So, you need to use the form of preloading within the query.

It'd be something like this:

`id = 123
query = from a in Article, where: a.id=^id, preload: [:comments]
query |> Repo.all`

Note that you need to use `^` sign when referring to already-bound variables inside the query.

Hope this helps..